# SAS Output Each Max Value By ID

Tags: sas, output, counter

I feel like I am making this more complicated than it should be.  I have a sample dataset below with an ID column and a Counter column.  The counter column resets and I would like to create a dataset containing only the rows where the counter column is the max value before it resets again.  My dataset also has thousands of ID's that I would need to do this for.

```
data test;
    infile datalines delimiter=",";
    informat    ID $3.
                TCOUNT 10.;             

    input ID $ TCOUNT $  ;

    datalines;
123,1
123,2
123,3
123,4
123,1
123,2
123,3
123,1
123,2

;

run;
```

and my desired output in a new table would look like...

```
   ID    TCOUNT
   123     4
   123     3
   123     2
```

Comment: Not sure why you use list input specifying TCOUNT as character (`TCOUNT $`) when the prior INFORMAT causes TCOUNT to be numeric (`TCOUNT 10.`).  I was surprised the LOG didn't have a NOTE: about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easiest/clearest to first assign a label to each of the non-decreasing TCOUNT blocks of observations.

```
data groups;
  set test;
  by id ;
  if first.id then group=0;
  if first.id or tcount<lag(tcount) then group+1;
run;
```

Then it is a simple matter to find the last observation in each group.

```
data want;
  set groups;
  by id group;
  if last.group;
run;
```